# How to minimize file search runtime complexity?

Tags: c#, .net-core

i wrote an application which is a custom console that allows execution of various commands. One of the commands allows to find a file's full path, according to part of its name. The input data is a string, which equals to part\full name of the file.

**My question is - how to minimize the search code runtime complexity as much as possible?**

Here is the command's code:

```
using CustomConsole.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Shell_Commander.Commands
{
    class FindFileCommand : ICommand
    {
        private string _findFileCommandName = "findfile";
        public string Name { get { return _findFileCommandName; } set { _findFileCommandName = value; } }

        public string Execute(string parameters)
        {
            var fileLocations = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

            try
            {
                var splittedParameters = parameters.Split(" ");
                var initialLocation = splittedParameters[0];
                var fileName = splittedParameters[1];

                foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(initialLocation, "*.*", SearchOption.A­llDirectories))
                {
                    fileLocations.Add(filePath, false);

                    if (Path.GetFileName(filePath) == fileName || Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) == fileName)
                    {
                        fileLocations[filePath] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            bool fileFound = false;
            string returnedOutput = "";
            foreach (var location in fileLocations.Keys)
            {
                if (fileLocations[location])
                {
                    returnedOutput += $"The file found in path: {location}\n";
                    Console.Write(returnedOutput);
                    fileFound = true;
                }
            }

            if (!fileFound)
            {
                returnedOutput = "The file not found in this path";
                Console.WriteLine(returnedOutput);
                return returnedOutput;
            }
            return returnedOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

Example - for the input parameters "c:\temp test", the output can be:

```
The file found in path: c:\temp\test.json
The file found in path: c:\temp\test.json
The file found in path: c:\temp\test.xml
The file found in path: c:\temp\test.json
The file found in path: c:\temp\test.xml
The file found in path: c:\temp\test\test.json
```

Comment: Why not let [Directory.GetFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) do the work in the first place? Instead of listing all files, adding them to a dictionary and iterating over the whole list twice, tell `GetFiles` to only return files matching a pattern like `"*"+fileName+"*"`. If you want to stick to your current approach, consider using [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8) and use a linked list that only contains the matched files.

Comment: I'm going to split hairs a tiny bit. We don't need to think so much about minimizing runtime complexity. Once the code is compiled and executing complexity is less of a concern. What matters more is design-time complexity. That is, can we look at the code and understand what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply your foreach like this

```
var fileLocations  =  Directory.GetFiles(initialLocation, $"{filePath}.*", SearchOption.A­llDirectories);

 foreach (var location in fileLocations)
 {
       returnedOutput += $"The file found in path: {location}\n";
       Console.Write(returnedOutput);
 }
```

The rest of the code also can be simplified.